# Prevent color adjustment in ViewportTexture

Tags: shaders, godot-4

In Godot 4.1.1, I'm trying to use ViewportTextures to capture values generated by some shaders for use in another shader. One SubViewport is capturing the result of an unshaded spatial shader on a [full-screen quad](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/advanced_postprocessing.html). However, when I sample the texture, I don't get exactly what the shader produced. It looks like the colors are adjusted. How can I prevent that?

Here's a simplified setup to show the issue:

```
Node3D
  MeshInstance3D(QuadMesh, postprocess.gdshader)
  Camera3D
  SubViewport2D(disable_3d = true)
    ColorRect(Full Rect, 2d.gdshader)
  SubViewport3D(own_world_3d = true)
    MeshInstance3D(QuadMesh, 3d.gdshader)
    Camera3D

// 2d.gdshader
shader_type canvas_item;
void fragment() { COLOR = vec4(UV, 0.4, 1.0); }

// 3d.gdshader
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;
void vertex() { POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0); }
void fragment() { ALBEDO = vec3(SCREEN_UV, 0.4); }

// postprocess.gdshader
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform sampler2D SubViewport2D;
uniform sampler2D SubViewport3D;

void vertex() { POSITION = vec4(VERTEX, 1.0); }
void fragment() {
    vec3 col1 = vec3(SCREEN_UV, 0.4);
    vec3 col2 = texture(SubViewport2D, SCREEN_UV).rgb;
    vec3 col3 = texture(SubViewport3D, SCREEN_UV).rgb;
    // Put col2 on the left, col3 on the right.
    bool left = SCREEN_UV.x < 0.5;
    // Put col1 on even pixels.
    bool even = fract((SCREEN_UV * VIEWPORT_SIZE).x * 0.5) < 0.5;
    ALBEDO = even ? col1 : (left ? col2 : col3);
}
```

In the last shader, I expect `col2` and `col3` to equal `col1`. The output indicates that `col2 = col1`, while `col3` is visually similar but not the same:

[image]

I tried adding a WorldEnvironment to SubViewport3D but it didn't make a difference. [This issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/54122) looks relevant but I'm not sure.

Comment: This looks like it might be the difference between linear and gamma-corrected (sRGB) colour space. Do you see any options with those keywords in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is due color conversion (as DMGregory guesses), then I think your `sampler2D` need `source_color`. Example:

```
uniform sampler2D image : source_color;
```

The `source_color` hint is the replacement of Godot 3 `hint_albedo` for Godot 4.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#uniforms):

> It's important to understand that textures that are supplied as color require hints for proper sRGB->linear conversion (i.e. source_color), as Godot's 3D engine renders in linear color space.

Note: The hint `source_color` also works vector colors.

---

You might also want to check the `WorldEnviroment`, in particular if there is any color correction set. *And I don't know if Tone mapping could be an issue.*

Comment: `source_color` did the trick, thanks!